# Error with PHP 8

Tags: php

Hi i use a widget with php code

on php7.4 everything ok

with php 8 i have an error....

Warning: Undefined variable $post in /xxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php(27) : eval()'d code on line 2

Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /xxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php(27) : eval()'d code on line 2

Warning: Undefined variable $post in /xxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php(27) : eval()'d code on line 3

Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /xxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php(27) : eval()'d code on line 3

My code:

```
<?php
if (get_the_terms($post->ID, 'ausstattung')) {
  $taxonomy_ar = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'ausstattung');
echo "";
  $output = '<ul>';
  foreach ($taxonomy_ar as $taxonomy_term) {
    $output .= '<li>'. $taxonomy_term->name .'</li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';

  echo $output;
}
?>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: [Someone else posted a similar issue a while back](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/412232/3276), so maybe this is a 7.4->8 issue, but I'd be surprised. (They never followed up with a resolution though.) How is that PHP file being loaded? Is it definitely run from within WordPress, at a point when the post is loaded? You might need to explicitly `global $post;`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a global variable called `$post` in your code, but this variable is `not defined`.

To fix this issue, you can try defining the $post variable at the top of your script:

```
 <?php
    global $post;
    
    if (get_the_terms($post->ID, 'ausstattung')) {
      $taxonomy_ar = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'ausstattung');
    echo "";
      $output = '<ul>';
      foreach ($taxonomy_ar as $taxonomy_term) {
        $output .= '<li>'. $taxonomy_term->name .'</li>';
      }
      $output .= '</ul>';
    
      echo $output;
    }
    ?>
```